# How Qi charger reads data from receiver

Tags: wireless-charging

I saw a guy making Qi receiver module with ATTiny13A: [Qi wireless power receiver from scratch](http://blog.vinu.co.in/2019/04/qi-wireless-power-receiver-from-scratch.html).

In his circuit, secondary shorted through capacitors to ground to send data.

My question is how transmitter side (base) reads this data?

[image]

Comment: You have nothing driving the gates of Q1 and Q2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the output is loaded, the power draw to the transmitter increases because of coupling between the coils.

The resulting current/voltage fluctuation is monitored, demodulated and read as data. The data flow is only possible from (power) receiver to transmitter.

You can find a lot more information in [this](http://cache.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/app_note/AN4701.pdf) application note from NXP/Freescale entitled **Demodulating Communication Signals of
Qi-Compliant Low-Power Wireless Charger
Using MC56F8006 DSC**,

Answer (score 0):

The tuned LC high Q resonance at 100kHz is modulated in bi-phase to target where the resonant coils can receive the modulated carrier.  The receiver then drives the gate to return a ping back and then an ID response with power demand.

When the mutual coupling is good with Gap<< diameter efficient low loss carrier power transfer is possible to a diode bridge cap not a 10uH cap. The buildup of voltage depends on this C ratio of nF to uF requiring 1000 cycles for the time constant if 22nF/2nF to 10uF ~1100:1 cycles

Coil inductance and high tolerance caps may require tuning.

The Q is thus XL(100kHz) /RdsOn/2.